# My javascript function won't work only if the page has fully loaded

Tags: javascript, html

I want to disable an input text after user click on other input tag with checkbox type,

the problem is the daterange input text wont disable everytime i click on checkbox, can anyone help?

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("daterange").disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<div class="item form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Date <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" class="form-control date" placeholder="Choose multiple dates">
    <p style="color: white">
      <input type="checkbox" name="everyday" id="everyday" onclick="myFunction()" value="everyday" class="flat" /> Everyday
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT :**
I just realized that when the page is not fully loaded it can work as i expected, but if the page is fully loaded, it seems something make the function not working

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. Can you help to clarify?

Comment: it cant work as i expected in my localhost, im using laravel, but i just realized it actually work in this snippets, i dont know where the problem might come from

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to use [alpineJS](https://alpinejs.dev/) in laravel

```
<div class="item form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" for="email">Date <span class="required">*</span>
        </label>
  <div x-data="{ inputDisabled: false }"  class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
    <input x-bind:disabled="inputDisabled"  type="text" name="daterange" id="daterange" class="form-control date" placeholder="Choose multiple dates">
    <p style="color: white">
      <input x-on:click="inputDisabled = true" type="checkbox" name="everyday" id="everyday"  value="everyday" class="flat" /> Everyday
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

if you using laravel brezze, alpine JS already include on it.
we can easily to manipulate our DOM without writting a lot code of JS. Just write in in inline HTML

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable the "daterange" input text when the checkbox is clicked, you can modify your JavaScript function like-
In the updated function, you can check the state of the "everyday" checkbox using the checked property. If the checkbox is checked, disable the "daterange" input by setting its disabled property to true. If the checkbox is not checked, we enable the "daterange" input by setting its disabled property to false.